# How to get rid of carpet indents

Tags: home, furniture, carpet

We are redoing our living room (it has a carpet floor), so we are moving a lot of furniture around. The biggest problem is that this leaves a lot of ugly indentation marks on the carpet. There are about 15 or 16 marks from the legs and then one big line that would be revealed with the new configuration of furniture. I've been trying to think of something that would get rid of the marks, but I can't think of anything.

[image: Line Indentation Mark]  [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Vacuum over them
   The simplest and easiest option, but not always effective if the marks are deep.
2. Vacuum over them *with a crevice tool*
   The same suction over a very small space is more likely to pull the carpet fibers back to their original position.
3. Scratch them out with a credit card or similar plastic tool
   This is a last resort. Anything that pushes the carpet fibers back up will help.

In the future, try to periodically move furniture around (even just an inch or so diagonally) to prevent deeply ingrained marks from forming.

Answer (score 6):

You have to wash the carpet. It will soak with water and will return its shape.

You can do it in the bathroom with shower or outside with the appliance used for cleaning cars with water under pressure.

Or bring the carpet to the people who clean cars and they can do it for you.

Answer (score 5):

Moisture is quite efficient in removing carpet indents, and this is also a main effect of taking our carpet away to a carpet cleaning service or washing it.

Of course this can not be done on a carpeted floor when the carpet cannot be removed.

Nevertheless we still have some options to apply the necessary amount of moisture to make the carbet fibers stand up again. All of these have in common that we do have to take care to **not wet the carpet**, and to let it dry sufficiently to avoid water stains, deformations, or even molding.

#### Ice cubes

Gently rub the affected area with an ice cube. This will ensure that only little water gets into the fabric, and the mechanical action will help the fibers to get in line again. Take care to stop before the carpet is all wet. It is all about applying just a bit of humidity.

#### Steam iron

With a houshold steam iron we can apply steam at desired amounts but this may need testing as not all carpets are heat resistant. To further prevent damage to the carpet it will help to cover affected areas with a damp cloth or towel and iron the cloth or towel above. This can also be done with a non-steam iron.

#### Professional carpet cleaning machines

Larger areas may need a more throughout approach as can be achieved by renting a professional carpet cleaning machine. Wet cleaning machines may come with a special cleaning fluid that may work better than pure water. These machines will inevitably leave quite an amount of moisture in the carpet. We should carefully let it dry before we use the room again. To avoid molding we also need enough of ventilation. Therefore cleaning a carpet this way is better been done in summer.