# How do I prevent furniture from leaving dents in the carpet?

Tags: furniture, moving, carpet

Furniture tends to leave dents in carpet when left for any length of time. Specifically, my chair tends to leave imprints where I have it in my room. How would I go about preventing this?

Comment: Are you asking about dents(compression) or stains(discoloration)? Or both?

Comment: @ErinGoBragh dents.

Comment: Also see the following question for suggestions on removing dents (not preventing them).  http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/5763/how-to-get-rid-of-carpet-indents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Furniture coasters**](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#tbm=shop&q=furniture+coasters) work well. You can also make a furniture coaster from scrap carpet by cutting them into squares (or whatever shape makes you happy). Place the coaster between the leg/foot of the furniture and the carpet. It will not prevent the dents, but will reduce them as the weight of the furniture is spread across the coaster.

Comment: I'm iffy, I really doubt coasters help with the denting, I think they are more helpful when it comes to sliding furniture or scratching wooden floors

Comment: When I moved into a new home last year, I had this problem and I did this for the legs of a table. I cut them a little wider than the width of the leg to spread out the mass. I've come across some of the spiked coasters on Amazon which seem like they'd do the trick.
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Medipaq-CARPET-SAVERS-Furniture-spikes/dp/B002EWOGN4

Answer (score 2):

Furniture coasters with several push-pins jammed into them might do the trick.

[image: furniture coaster with push pins in it]

Since the push pins stick out of the bottom of the furniture coaster, they will be what touches the floor, not the coaster. Since they are narrow, they will most likely slide between the upright threads of the "pile" of your carpet, so none (or very few) of those threads should be bent. And since there are multiple thumbtacks, the weight of the furniture and anybody sitting in it will be somewhat well distributed (as opposed to just using a single thumbtack to raise the furniture).

You'll need to get pretty strong thumbtacks for this; plastic thumbtack heads may break. I'd imagine that metal or wood would be best. The heads should be as tall or almost as tall, as the length of your carpet's pile.

Comment: Or, you can buy "spiked" furniture coasters with the nubs already in them, like [these](http://www.floor-protection-resources.com/prodimages/Slipstick-Square-Carpet-Castor-Cups-Clear-300.jpg) or [these](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71Od71zX8WL._SX522_.jpg).

Comment: Hm, Interesting. Have you seen or read anything that says this will work? When you sprawl out across a couch at the end of a long day, not only are there vertical forces, but pretty substantial *horizontal* forces trying to push the couch across the floor. I suspect a tack-in-a-coaster will be wrenched free pretty easily in that scenario, and you'll end up with either broken tacks or (more likely) the tacks splayed out across the floor.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Good point. This was just off the top of my head. Tacks are the first thing I could think of that had the basic form I was looking for, but they may not be sturdy enough. (And J.R. pointed out that there are spiked furniture coasters which have certainly addressed the shear forces!)

Comment: @J.R. Cool! So someone else though of this solution already. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Fold a piece of paper 6 times. Make sure that the area of paper after folding 6 times is greater than c/s area of the leg. See that there are no edge point directly facing into the carpet and then put that paper below the leg. This hack should do the job temporarily.